# How to share a Single Domain SSL certificate across 2 ip addresses

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I have a wordpress website **example.com**. I have a single domain SSL certificate that can be used across multiple servers.

When a user visits **example.com**, or any subfolder expect forum , they access **server1** which is running apache.

When a user vists **example.com/forum** they are redirected to **server2** which runs nginx. How would I set such that both ip addresses are mapped under **example.com** such that the redirects are only internal and the domain remains **example.com** at all times

In my site apache vhost, I am using

```
Redirect permanent /forum http://server2ip
```

to redirect to server2

**EDIT ACCORDING TO LUCA'S ANSWER TO SET server1 as PROXY to SERVER2**

Here is my apache vhost config for the setup

```
VirtualHost *:80>
   RewriteEngine on
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAdmin me@example.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/example

   #Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
   # RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

   ProxyPass /forum https://server2ip/

   <Location /forum>
     ProxyPass https://server2ip/
     ProxyPassReverse https://server2ip/
   </Location>

   <Proxy *>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyHTMLEnable On
   ProxyHTMLURLMap https://server2ip/ /forum
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually redirecting the client to a different server. Assuming you configured DNS to point to `server1`, you want to mask the presence of `server2`. To do this configure apache as a reverse proxy and proxy `/forum` requests to `server2`. You do not need to configure `SSL` on `server2`.

Comment: @Luna Corti How would I go about Setting apache as a reverse proxy to server2..so that server2 runs on example.com/forum?

Comment: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_apache_as_a_reverse_proxy.html

Comment: ...I have updated my answer with my vhost config...i have never worked with a proxy before so excuse my noobiness

Comment: Is the proxying working? Are you getting any errors/have any issues with that setup?